# Samsung RV520 with 12.04 freezes while having WiFi and brightness control issues

Tags: wireless, laptop, freeze, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I have a new Samsung RV520 and have just installed Precise Pangolin 12.04 LTS.
I am having serious problems now with the wifi constantly disconnecting.  This then causes the brightness control to appear on the screen.  The screen starts flickering and then freezes the whole machine.   Indeed the brightness control doesn't work at all.

I am using a Intel Centrino N wireless card.

Please can anyone provide any guidance as to how to resolve these issue on this machine.

Many thanks for your help.

Output from lspci and dmesg:

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 130 (rev 34)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)

dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.917077] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.118837] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[   11.852357] iwlagn 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.168.5.2 build 35905
```

Comment: I don't see how WiFi relates to brightness controls. I count 3 issues on you side: 1. Laptop freezes 2. WiFi disconnects and 3. brightness crontrols don't work, am I right? That the system freezes/crashes very important, but isn't in the title. For brightness controls there already exists a question with answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134610/brightness-control-issue-samsung-rv520-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: There are also 2 questions for issues with Intel Centrino WiFi cards: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128870/wireless-dropping-with-an-intel-centrino-wireless-n-1030 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/125531/wireless-connection-with-a-centrino-wireless-n-1000-wont-last-longer-than-20-se Could you please add the output of `dmesg | grep -i firmware` and `lspci` to your question or as a comment if you cannot edit your question, please?

Comment: 1). dmesg | grep -i firmware produces:dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.917077] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.118837] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness